# how to insert datepicker into a jquery wizard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, wizard

I have created a jquery wizard form, and inside i have to insert an input -> datepicker, but it doesn't work.

Here is the input line:

`<label for="created">Creation date *</label><input name="created" id="created"  type="text">`

and here the simple javascript:

```
<script>
$('#created').datepicker();
</script>
```

I think the problem is due to the wizard that is rendered after that the JavaScript is loaded. 
Anyway, I still searching for a solution.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks
Gaetano

Answer (score 1):

Depending in where your code is placed in the page, the DOM is not ready yet (so the `$('#created')` selector does not return a match).

Add a DOM ready handler around your code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#created').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

Note: `$(function(){yourcode});` is a shortcut for `$(document).ready(function(){yourcode});`

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery ready function to initialize datepicker.

for example:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#created').datepicker();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. 
Just 12 days ago were released new features that allow you to initialize variables (or anything that might serve) and fires these ones when the wizard is initialized.

In my case I used the onInit() for event management.

At this [link](https://github.com/rstaib/jquery-steps/wiki/Settings#events) is possible to see all the specifications for the jQuery wizard-step.

Byez
Gaetano